# Who wins if the game ends with one player having 6 colonies and 1 or more players with 5 colonies?

Tags: cosmic-encounter

It is possible to end a game of Cosmic Encounter with 6 colonies (i.e. Parasite wild flare). The rules for the FFG version of Cosmic Encounter state that:

> The winner(s) are the first player(s) to have five colonies on any
>   planets outside his or her home system . . . It is possible, through
>   alliances and successful negotiations, to have more than one player
>   gain five colonies at the same time. In this case, the players share a
>   win.

This could be interpreted to mean 5 or more colonies, but the rules do not specifically say that. A devious tactic could be to invite someone along as ally to each achieve a 5th planet simultaneously, but then because the parasite flare was played the attacker ends with 6 colonies vs. the ally's 5 colonies.

So . . . who wins if the game ends with one player having 6 colonies and 1 or more players with 5 colonies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I received the following e-mailed answer from Jonathan Bove of FFG:

> Since all of the players fulfilled the victory condition at the same
>   time, it is a joint victory. However, this shouldn't stop the player
>   with 6 colonies from bragging about his or her intergalactic skills!

Since this is direct from FFG, I will take this to be the official answer.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is entirely up for player interpretation, but my opinion is: since Cosmic Encounter doesn't have rules for tie-breaking, and since situations where several player meet the victory conditions is interpreted as a shared victory - one player having MORE than 5 colonies is completely identical to this player having 5 colonies, thus he will share a victory with the players that have five colonies.